# large training dataset for a neural network: splitting the data into chunks and pass fitted weights from one chunk to another

Tags: neural-networks, scikit-learn

My data constitutes a few million observations, and am not able to load the entire data all at once on the memory (which seems to be the common practice with most packages such as scikit learn and Keras require). As a workaround, I was thinking to load data in smaller chunks, fit the model for that chunk (with the iteration number set at 1) get the weights, use the weights as the initial weight for the next chunk. Continue this until all data is used. Repeat this whole process many times (this would be the actual number of iteration). Does this process make sense?

My second question may be off topic, but does either of scikit learn or Keras  (or some other libraries) allow us to set the initial weights for a neural network?

Comment: Part of this is off-topic, more about using a program than using statistics. And part of it relates to statistics, namely when asking about "Does this process make sense." Put the statistical question upfront as in "How do I doooo this problem, like this?, if so how do I insert weights. Otherwise, it risks being closed here as off topic, and since it is a compound question, it may not find a home on a programming site either.

Comment: It makes perfect sense, what you want to do is called batch learning and every ml framework should support it. Batch size is one of many parameters to tune (most common size is 128-256) and can speed up convergence.